# create databricks external location on storage account

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I am trying to create an externel location in azure databricks that point to a storage account (not a gen2 datalake) 
I put this in the url 
 wasbs://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/ 
but I got this error 'url has invalid URI scheme wasbs. Valid URI schemes include s3, gs, s3n, r2, s3a, abfss' 
Is there any work around?

Comment: What is the code you are using? Add those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general Unity Catalog requires ADLS Gen 2, and don't work with Azure Blob - it's described in the documentation ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/get-started#--configure-and-grant-access-to-azure-storage-for-your-metastore) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-external-locations-and-credentials#requirements)):

> External locations must use Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage accounts that have a hierarchical namespace.